# How to achieve type narrowing for a function inside an heterogenous array

Tags: typescript

I made a `match` function that takes a value and an array of `[case, func]`, the value is compared to each `case` and if a match is found its associated `func` is called with the value as a parameter:

```
type Case<T> = [T | Array<T>, (value: T) => void];

const match = <V>(value: V, cases: Array<Case<V>>) => {
  for (const [key, func] of cases) {
    if (Array.isArray(key) ? key.includes(value) : key === value) {
      return func(value);
    }
  }
};
```

I want to make the value of each `func` narrows to its associated `case`, i.e:

```
// const value: string = "whatever";
match(value, [
  [
    "something",
    (v) => {
      // here, `v` should narrow to `"something"`
    }
  ],
  [
    ["other", "thing"],
    (v) => {
      // here, `v` should narrow to `"other" | "thing"`
    }
  ]
] as const);
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with this structure. Notice that the `V` type parameter is `"something" | "other" | "thing"`, and that type is passed as the `T` parameter to `Case`

Comment: We can express the requisite typings, but [ms/TS#53018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53018) means you simply will not get inference for `v`, unfortunately. Until and unless that is addressed you'd need to refactor if you want inference.  There are a number of possible refactorings; one is to use a helper function as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NVepvw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the link to #53018. Your example with the helper function is great, but I'll stick to my basic implementation for the time being since this was more a of quality of life improvement than something really required. I'm fine waiting for this to be properly supported by TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the correct typings for `match()` but it will not infer the callback parameter types the way you'd like. This is a missing feature in TypeScript. You'll either need to wait for that feature to be implemented (which might be never), refactor in some way, or give up.

---

The correct typing for `match()` looks like this:

```
const match = <V, C extends V[]>(
  value: V,
  cases: [...{ [I in keyof C]: Case<C[I]> }]
) => {
  for (const [key, func] of cases) {
    if (Array.isArray(key) ? key.includes(value) : key === value) {
      return func(value as never);
    }
  }
};
```

here the type of `cases` is not just `Array<Case<V>>`, which wouldn't try to keep track of the individual subtypes of `V` at each element of the array, and which furthermore isn't even correct for subtypes... for example, `Case<"something">` is not assignable to `Case<string>`, because although you can assign `"something"` to `string`, you *cannot* assign `(value: "something") => void` to `(value: string) => void`, due to the fact that [function types are *contravariant* in their inputs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types).

Instead, the type of `cases` is a [mapped array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) over the new [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `C` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a subtype of `V[]`.  Each element of `C` is wrapped with `Case<⋯>` to get the corresponding element of `cases`. So if `C` is specified by `["x", "y", "z"]`, then the type of `cases` is `[Case<"x">, Case<"y">, Case<"z">]`.

---

The hope is that if you call

```
const value: string = "whatever";
match(value, [
  [ "something", (v) => {} ],
  [ ["other", "thing"], (v) => { }]
]);
```

the compiler would infer `V` to be `string`, which does happen... and it would also infer `C` to be `[ "something", "other" | "thing" ]`, which unfortunately does *not* happen.  And even if it *did* happen, the [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) of `v` in those callbacks wouldn't manage to happen in time.

It's difficult for the type checker to infer a generic type argument like `C` while at the same time inferring a contextual type for function parameters like `c`, when they are mutually dependent.  The currently open issue about this phenomenon in general is [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599).  For `match()` in particular the most applicable issue is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#53018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53018), since we're trying to infer `C` from a mapped type (inference from mapped types is sometimes called a "reverse" mapped type) and then contextually infer `v` in each element.

For now this isn't implemented, and so the above call ends up failing to infer `C` properly. It's just `string[]`, which means that both instances of `v` are of type `string`, which isn't what you want.

---

I don't know whether microsoft/TypeScript#53018 will ever be implemented, or even necessarily that the above code will work directly if it is.  For now all we can do is give up or work around it.

There are lots of possible workarounds; the easiest one might be to use a helper function inside the call to `match()` to infer your cases one at a time instead of all at once.  Something like this:

```
match(value, [
  c("something", (v) => { }),
  c(["other", "thing"], (v) => { })
]);
```

where `c` is defined as

```
const c = <const T,>(
  value: T | Array<T>,
  handler: (value: T) => void
): Case<T> => [value, handler];
```

This works; the first `v` is inferred as `"something"` and the second `v` is inferred as `"other" | "thing"`, and thus `C` in the call to `match()` is inferred as `["something", "other"|"thing"]`, as desired.  Each call to `c` only needs to worry about inferring one thing, not a whole array of things.

Yes, this is just a workaround, but it's fairly lightweight; all you need to do is replace `[xxx,yyy]` with `c(xxx,yyy)`, which is only one extra keystroke.  Yes, there's some cognitive overhead, so that's why this is a workaround and not a direct solution.

Whether this or some other workaround is acceptable or not depends on your use cases, and since the question doesn't ask for workarounds then this is probably out of scope for the question as asked, so I'll stop now.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgZwgHgCoD4oF4oG1VQA+UAggE5lwhroA0UAFAG5wA2ArhAFxSoCU2TEwD2ASwAmAXQDcAWABQChQGNhAOwTAoAWzjBlAC2xRkANXowoEAB7AIa8Qiinck9AwVQoLDt2e1PKGVECAQeXAA6KIBvPABJKFE1KABrCBBhADNYSR54JGQYXDi3KABfSQUBLExowMzhMkZVDS1cNJB6TPY1ZUkoLKCQhAE6+S8vUWyGckoQCNEEWaoGDoEAflT0hd6OcVDmNk4BHg7sLBwfY6gxiYmyCGB2MmTu3sPfKEQoNQgmCDIfDk4wmZUCYPkZWBKnUmm8Rz8mjISQA5sYAEQAdwMej+APRwN0+gMH049FwgVw6IQwm0jwMqPR9GY1Vq5UkARBAHouXc+XcAHrrSlU4TAAz4+jo8WMjmMJism7swI8-lqtVChSSIFKeSq9HKdGJJwNJoGkJMqDivQAcicKOEwnEVjUwnYKKMpp0EHooUgylEbFYICgCCSymg5qQRsWXygDyQZH+zsxjWdSSgACsEDDWkFjMgWnDULR3IErn4CMRltQMJyvDiHKwATxSZXFSIJFU8iEaII8BX6I3xM2yDJdbqiYY2+TAsoGNTafTGcyFf3YmU+PWoKr1XzNSD56LxZKoNKGWoUei5Sz1+U+CreXvn1AD9rofIgA)